# Could not 'watch' on gmail API

Tags: gmail-api, google-cloud-pubsub

> "Error sending test message to Cloud PubSub projects/google.com:apisexplorerconsole/topics/my-new-topic : User not authorized to perform this action."

I have granted full access to service accounts, but no luck. Im able to subscribe to a topic and receive the message i publish, but could not move on with this gmail watch.

Comment: You may want to check the follow the solutions of these related SO post [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32066297/5995040) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30990958/5995040). The solution as stated from the links are setting the correct request format, check if gmail is granted to publish in Pubsub and make sure you've correctly setIamPolicy on it. Hope this helps.